# How to style an <output> with color?

Tags: html, css

I have a html output form

```
<output name=foo></output>
```

that gives out precalculated values. I'd like to underlay the output with a color, but I can't find anything on how to do it, only for input forms.(which seem to behave very differently).

Any tips?

Comment: Define "underlay". Are you asking how to set the background colour?

Comment: Yes, but only of the field.

Comment: It's exactly the same as for input elements.

Comment: I realize that now - man that was easy. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you mean *underline*? Anyway, an output is an element like any other, and can be styled as such:

```css
/* Default */
output {
  text-decoration: underline;
  background-color: yellow;
}
    
/* Emphasise 'foo' */
output[name=foo] {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<output name="foo">Foo output</output>
<output name="bar">Bar output</output>
```

Of course, if it doesn't have content, some styling like text color and underline doesn't have effect.

Comment: I am still struggeling with css, but I got it working, thanks!

Comment: but it changing the color of text also.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change only the underline color, use the beloe one.

```
<output style="text-decoration: underline; color: red;">
 <span style="color: #CCC;">text with red linethrough and black text</span>
</output>
```

The above code will only change the color of underline.

Answer (score 0):

you can style by selecting output tag

```
output {
    color : red;
}
```